# Unable to figure out where the metrics are shown or stored after running sample protractor-perf conf.js

Tags: selenium, protractor, performance-testing

I am new to protractor-perf. I have installed it and tried to execute the following sample conf.js and example.js

conf.js :- https://github.com/axemclion/protractor-perf/blob/master/test/conf.js

example.js :- https://github.com/axemclion/protractor-perf/blob/master/test/example.spec.js

when I run **protractor-perf conf.js**. It runs fine and I get to see in command prompt that it passed. But how and where do I get to see the metrics ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the metrics we need to run the following line of code which would log the metrics on console:

```
if (perfRunner.isEnabled) {  
    expect(perfRunner.getStats('meanFrameTime')).toBeLessThan(60);
    perfRunner.getStats().then(console.log.bind(console)); // logs the Metrics
}
```